# Why does my Bevel move vertices along the edges instead of bevel them?

Tags: edit-mode, edges, bevel

At one side Bevel works perfectly, but with similar edge on the other side is a mess. The same problem with the other edges. Bevel goes flat, vertices run along the edges.

I have no doubled vertices. Recalculating Normals for all these vertices didn't help. I have no internal faces. There are edges between all these vertices.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). There is a known Bevel tool bug, that causes similar behavior. Would you mind [sharing your .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can take a closer look?

Comment: May be your object has a non uniform scale. Try to apply the scale by pressing CTRL+A in Object Mode.

Comment: @FFeller i've already done Ctrl+A to make even bevels.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ I grouped normal and bugged vertecies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was caused by one flipped face.

The *Bevel tool* was confused, not knowing which way to go.
Recalculate *Normals*, so they're all pointing outwards.
Then the Bevel tool will work correctly.

*Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*

[image]

Comment: You opened to me this beautiful Face Orientation checkbox. Can't say enough words to thank you)

Comment: Happy to help :). It saved me so many times from going mad.