# Bevel tool creating unexpected geometry

Tags: bevel

I am having problems with the bevel tool where blender creates unexpected geometry. I have two examples where I don't understand why things are going wrong:

Number 1:
I tried to create a revolver cylinder - following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnftMW0Yhzk until about minute 6:32 - and I connected the holes on each side with the bridge edge loop tool. However, when I then tried to bevel the resulting edge around that hole, blender produced uneven and strange geometry.
[image]

Now, when I got rid of the faces inside of the loop and extruded faces from the edge loop, the bevel tool worked fine. I checked for unconnected vertices or double vertices on the same spot; and I also made sure all the transformations are applied. But no change, so I am confused as to what the problem is.

Problem 2:
I tried to create a sword with a fairly simple geometry. But when trying to bevel one side blender just seems to connect the different vertices in the wrong way, which messes up the geometry.

It looks like this: [image]

Just as before, I removed vertices by distance and doublechecked that all vertices and edges are connected. All the transformations are also applied. This model has some ngons but around the side where I want to bevel all the faces are quads; not even sure if that matters. But again, I have no idea what the problem is and would really appreciate if someone could explain what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, I should do more research before posting. The problem was that the normals got messed up. The answer can be found under this post:
[Why my Bevel move verticies along the edges instead of bevel them?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165291/why-my-bevel-move-verticies-along-the-edges-instead-of-bevel-them)